# Finding maximum possible size of subset given conditions

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming, subset

This is a problem from a past contest. Unfortunately that contest doesn’t have a editorial so I am asking the question. You can verify that the contest is over: [Problem Description](http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/abc2/)

I tried to solve it using DP using variation of subset sum problem. But I don't know how to enforce the conditions that at start of race the current fuel should be more than required in the race. I am calculating difference and seeing if there is a sum possible less than the initial fuel using subset sum. But in this case I can't enforce the constraint.

Can anyone help me formulate a Dynamic Programming algorithm for the question. Or if it is not possible using Dynamic Programming, what other approach can I use.

Answer (score 4):

If the order of the races were fixed, then perhaps it would be easier to find a sufficiently fast dynamic program. I'm going to outline a *structure theorem*, that is, a way to add constraints that leaves at least one optimal solution. The DP can exploit these constraints, which, in this case, amount to a race ordering. This is a general strategy for improving the running times of dynamic programs.

Consider a particular racing schedule. Suppose that Chandler participates in a race with a net fuel loss immediately preceding a race with a net fuel gain. There's no reason that he can't do the gain race then the loss race: he'll have more fuel at the start of both than he did in a feasible schedule. Thus, we can assume that Chandler schedules all gains before all losses.

Suppose that Chandler participates in back-to-back gain races with prerequisite fuel amounts s and s'. If s > s', then again he can make the switch and find himself with more starting fuel for both races. We can assume that the gains are ordered by increasing prerequisite fuel.

Suppose that Chandler participates in back-to-back loss races with prerequisite fuel amounts s and s'. If s < s', then, well, you know the drill. We can assume that the losses are ordered by decreasing prerequisite fuel. With a little tie-breaking, this concludes our total order on races.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am a beginner in DP and am not to grasp what you say.

Comment: In my mind, his solution really isn't DP.  He has proved that a given greedy ordering will always be optimal.

Comment: So which algorithm should I use?

Comment: @RobNeuhaus Yes, it's not the DP. The DP does the optimization over schedules where the races are run in the specified order. The table after processing each race is a map from number of races entered to maximum fuel available given that level of participation.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat So can you please explain how should I proceed, any start would really help.

Comment: @TejasPatel Loop through the races in the specified order. To update the table in response to a race: to run k races, I either can run k races before this one, or, assuming that I can run k - 1 races before this one and have enough fuel to start, run those k - 1 followed by this one.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat But the order of races is not fixed, so will this approach work?

Comment: @TejasPatel Yes, because this particular order provably always works.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I am sorry but I still don't understand your approach. Can you please write a pseudo code in your answer. That would really help.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Why did you remove last line ( Can be solved using greedy algorithm from your answer) Is it not possible to do so?

Comment: @TejasPatel It might be possible, but the idea that I had works only for the gains.